# Installation of “monitord” under Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian

Can anyone tell me how to install the program monitord under raspberry pi (raspbian)? Maybe a tutorial or smth.?

I checked google but found nothing....

Comment: would you care to explain, what is `monitord` and why do you think you need it to get installed?

Comment: Monitord is a program to receive and decode the radio frequencies of firefighters, ambulance - in Germany

Comment: If you could link to the programs web site (preferably in English) we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't try but it should work:

1. Download the sources from http://www.monitord.de/?article=2
2. Untar
3. In the folder you extracted at step 2 open a terminal and type **./configure**
4. Compile the code usin **make**
5. Install the program using **make install** as **sudo**

This is a typical installation of a software from source code on a Linux OS. So it should work on Raspbian too. But you'll have to deal with the dependencies of the program and sometimes that's really hard.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the same thing as @23ars, but a little change. Install checkinstall.  Follow 23ars suggestions, but replace step 5. With

```
 sudo checkinstall -D
```

(when using checkinstall, if the version auto populates, make sure it starts with a number  not a letter (like v10.1), if it has a letter just press 3 and change the release to start with a number.

Then follow the easy prompts. This will use checkinstall to install as well as make a. deb for you that you can back up and use again if you ever have to reinstall OS. Or if monitord updates, you can easily uninstall old version with

```
 sudo dpkg -r monitord
```

And then recompile/install new version same way